# Nexcom VTC 6200 installing Android 4.2 or higher

Tags: linux, hardware, android-x86, hardware-requirements

I've got a [Nexcom VTC 6200-NI-DK](http://www.nexcom.co.uk/Products/mobile-computing-solutions/in-vehicle-pc/in-vehicle-pc/transportation-computer-vtc-6200-ni-dk/ContactSales) box wich is a bit obsolete but nevertheless I'd like to install Android on it. As far as I understand its spec is far from being top notch:

- CPU - `Intel Atom D510 Dual Core 1.66GHz`
- GPU - `N/A`
- RAM - `2Gb`

I've tried different images of [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) from Android 8.1 Oreo down to Android 4.2 JellyBean but I could only run them in `VESA 800x600` mode or lower and their performance was inacceptable (I tried to switch off animation and optimize Android from inside, didn't work).

My question, is it possible at all to achieve good-enough performance of Android OS on this piece of hardware? Would it make sense to research into making a custom build, possibly with custom drivers or dropping some unnecessary parts of Android, e.g. [media services](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture)? This box is going to be used very specifically, pretty much for calculations using some Android software, but interaction with UI should be smooth.

Comment: Have you tried the CM builds (CynogenMod or LineageOS)?

Comment: @Zackary As I know, CM only supports ARM architecture. I've read some info on LineageOS as it supports x86 but I didn't try it. Do you think its performance may be for some reason better than Android-x86?

Answer (score 1):

I used to own a PC with that same CPU. It ran Windows 10 so-so, that is well enough and not too terribly slow. It should run Linux acceptably fast. Android should run as fast as Linux. I'm not sure why your Android experience with it hasn't been positive since Android is simply a different OS on a Linux kernel. You might try running a Linux distribution on it to see if your hardware will run acceptably. If you are still set on running Android instead of Linux, you can continue your efforts if you found your hardware could handle Linux.

Comment: I tried to run Ubuntu 16.04 from USB drive (same as I did with Android-x86) and performance sucked too. Did your PC have discrete/on-board GPU ? Cuz I have suspicion that actually not having one at all makes the difference.

Comment: I had the small Intel mother board with the large heat sink, no fan. I was also running 2 GB RAM. The Intel system chip had on board graphics, but back then it was nothing to speak of - buying a video card was pretty much mandatory for anything other than casual computing. Maybe your system has one of the older slow disk I/O chips that is a throughput choke point for the system. I had an old Acer laptop that was like that. It originally came with Win XP. I had it upgraded to Win10. It was okay with CPU functions (Celeron single core), but anything to do with disk I/O, I had to wait and wait.

Comment: I'm not sure the I/O is guilty in my case as what I do is just simply loading Android into memory from USB-memory stick. Of course, I/O is a bit slow and loading takes 5-7min but then it shouldn't massively rely on disk. Also, I see hiccups during very simple operations like button clicks and changing radio-button selection which in most of scenatios should not perform disk reads/writes. Thanks for your help, btw.

Comment: I don't know if the USB controller is independent of the I/O controller or not. You're right though. Lag with clicks is a CPU issue - not likely the fault of the Atom processor, but rather the x86 Android implementation.